# How to delete Google Calendar Event from API (Using Bubble.io)

Tags: api, calendar

I am trying to use the Google Calendar API to enable users of my application to create events, retrieve events info, and finally delete events in their google calendar directly from my app, which is by the way built in *bubble.io*.

I have successfully setup the first 2 usecases, but I am having issues setting up the last one.

I have tried to follow the API documentation from google, but without any luck so far. See screenshot attached of how my call looks right now - I have tried various variations of this call, but always get an error with `"code: 404, Message: not found"`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add parameters like as follow :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3JMy.png)

You can find more info here : https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

Let me know if it was of any help,
A proud member of Bubble community.